# Is $f$ a probability density function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I don't know what the answer to this problem is. Can someone help me?

Suppose $f$ is a *nonnegative* real valued integrable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is a random variable. State whether the following statement is true or false:

$f$ *is a probability density function of* $X$ *if and only if* $\forall \ a \in \mathbb{R},$

$$P(X\ge a)= \int _a^\infty f(x)dx$$
If it is true, why; and if not ,give a  counter example.

As far as I could do, I feel that the statement is true. Am I right?

I have one more problem ( if I am right) : what are the sufficient things I have to prove here so as to show the statement to be correct?

Comment: It is true. The reason is due to the measure theoretic definition of the density function. In this case probably one needs to find the integral as $F(\infty)-F(a)=1-F(a)=P(X\geq a)$

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Can you please help me without measure theory? I have not learnt that yet

Comment: @Qwerty What is your definition of density function?

Comment: @Crostul :There $\textbf{is }$no definition... Take any one... The thing to judge is whether the italicised statement is true for all definitions or not. One counter example, and we are done..

Comment: @Qwerty Well, my definition of density function is exactly the one you have there, so in my opinion there is nothing to prove.

Comment: You're asked to prove that "f is <term> if and only if f satisfies <condition>", so surely you must be given the definition of <term> in order for this to make sense.

Comment: @Crostul : dear user , the question I gave was given as a part of an examination, and was with 12 points.. How can there be nothing to prove?

Comment: @StefanHansen : the <term> is the usual one: $f(x)\ge 0$ and $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) = 1$

Comment: @Qwerty: That definition doesn't involve X.

Comment: @StefanHansen : $x$ are the values taken by $X$.

Comment: @Qwerty: That definition still doesn't depend on $X$, so surely this can't be the definition of '$f$ being a probability density function of $X$'.

Comment: @StefanHansen : Let me frame it this way. I am a student, who was given the above question (verbatim) starting from "$f$ is a *probability* $\dots$ counter example " . It consisted of 12 points. What was I to answer?

Comment: @Qwerty: That depends on what your definition of '$f$ being a probability density function of $X$' is. Surely, this must be stated in the textbook or lecture notes you are following.

Comment: @StefanHansen : Well, can you help me in this way? Suppose you were given an exam, and asked this same question.. You don't have authenticity to challenge the question maker, and its a compulsory question. What would you write? Mind you, 12 points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36360/discussion-between-qwerty-and-stefan-hansen).

Comment: I would start by taking a look in my textbook if I didn't know the precise definition of a probability density function.

Comment: @StefanHansen : Can you please tell me where I am going wrong in the definition?